# Performing web scraping using selenium on influenster.com. I am getting just one scraped review even though it was in loop and the xpath was correct

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, screen-scraping

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import configparser
from datetime import datetime

parser = configparser.RawConfigParser()
parser.read('config.ini')

url= parser['PROPERTIES']['URL']
END_DATE = datetime.strptime(parser['DATE']['END'], '%Y-%m-%d')
START_DATE=datetime.strptime(parser['DATE']['START'],'%Y-%m-%d')
# Setting up driver options
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
# Setting up Path to chromedriver executable file
CHROMEDRIVER_PATH =r'C:\Users\HP\Desktop\INTERNSHIP\influenster\chromedriver.exe'
# Adding options
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
# Setting up chrome service
service = ChromeService(executable_path=CHROMEDRIVER_PATH)
# Establishing Chrom web driver using set services and options
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)

driver.get(url)

reviews=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="app-base"]/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]')
count=0
item_list = []

for review in reviews:
    item={       
        'username': review.find_element_by_xpath(".//a[contains(@class,'name')]").text,
}
    item_list.append(item)
    print(item_list)
```

[OUTPUT IS JUST ONE NAME AND NOT ALL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nERWs.png)
I need to scrape all the reviews from https://www.influenster.com/reviews/loreal-paris-elvive-extraordinary-oil-deep-nourishing-shampoo-and-conditioner-set-126-fl-oz. Even I am running a loop I am getting only one username. Please help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You getting only 1 review because XPath locator you are using `//*[@id="app-base"]/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]` returns only 1 element, so your `for` loop is performed only once.
You can improve this code by improving that XPath locator.
Also you need to close the cookies banner there.
Also you need to add a wait to waif for elements to be clickable / visible before you accessing them, as following.
This should work better:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import configparser
from datetime import datetime

parser = configparser.RawConfigParser()
parser.read('config.ini')

url= parser['PROPERTIES']['URL']
END_DATE = datetime.strptime(parser['DATE']['END'], '%Y-%m-%d')
START_DATE=datetime.strptime(parser['DATE']['START'],'%Y-%m-%d')
# Setting up driver options
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
# Setting up Path to chromedriver executable file
CHROMEDRIVER_PATH =r'C:\Users\HP\Desktop\INTERNSHIP\influenster\chromedriver.exe'
# Adding options
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
# Setting up chrome service
service = ChromeService(executable_path=CHROMEDRIVER_PATH)
# Establishing Chrom web driver using set services and options
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
driver.get(url)
# The 2 lines below is what I actually added here + necessary imports
# and `wait` object initialization   
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))).click()
reviews = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".conversations-left .item")))
count=0
item_list = []

for review in reviews:
    item={       
        'username': review.find_element_by_xpath(".//a[contains(@class,'name')]").text,
}
    item_list.append(item)
    print(item_list)
```

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks a lot. Can you please guide me on how to scrape the star rating

Comment: probably yes, but since this will be a new issue please ask a new question and will try to help there too if I will can

Comment: Stackoverflow rules limiting each question to be about 1 specific issue. This makes the questions and answers here more reusable